# ansible how to compare two strings

Tags: ansible

Could you please explain to me how to compare values - strings in Ansible to set up the correct variable?

```
  - name: Set directory
    set_fact:
      full_directory: "{{ directory }}/{{folder}}"
    when: 
      "{{ test }}"" == "string"
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

Answer (score 3):

if test is a variable

```
when: test == "string"
```